# If I have the name of a file, how do I search a folder for a file that contains that filename?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have an image with the filename `media_httpfarm3static_mAyIi.jpg`.

I would like to search the parent folder and all subfolders of that parent folder for a file that contains that name - it doesn't have to be the EXACT name, but must contain that string.

E.g. this file should be returned: `11605730-media_httpfarm3static_mAyIi.jpg`

So this is a 2-part question:

1. How do I achieve the above?
2. Once I have the file, how do I return the path for that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Dir::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [`File::absolute_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-absolute_path):

```
partial_name = "media_httpfarm3static_mAyIi.jpg"
Dir["../**/*#{partial_name}"].each do |filename|
  puts File.absolute_path(filename)
end
```

This uses the glob `"../**/*media_httpfarm3static_mAyIi.jpg"` (go up one directory, then search all sub directories (recursively), for any file ending in the partial string `"media_httpfarm3static_mAyIi.jpg"`. The relative paths are then returned in an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html).

You can use [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-each), [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map), etc. to convert this into what you need. To convert a relative path, into an absolute path, just pass it to [`File::absolute_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-absolute_path).

Once you have the absolute path, you can use it to open the file, read the file, etc.

### On File Paths

The glob `"../**/*media_httpfarm3static_mAyIi.jpg"` is relative to the current working directory. Normally, this is the directory from which the program was run. Not the directory of the source file. This can change using various utilities to change it.

To always use a glob relative to the source code file, try:

```
Dir[File.expand_path('../**/*#{partial_name}', __FILE__)]
```

You can also use:

```
Dir[File.join(__dir__, "..", "**", "*#{partial_name}")]
```

**Note:** `__dir__` was added in Ruby 2.0. For older versions of ruby use `File.dirname(__FILE__)`

In the first code sample [`File::absolute_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-absolute_path) was used. In the last sample [`File::expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) is used. In most situations these can be used interchangeably. There is a minor difference, per the documentations:

#### [`File::absolute_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-absolute_path)

> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are
>   referenced from the current working directory of the process unless
>   dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting
>   point. If the given pathname starts with a “~” it is NOT expanded, it
>   is treated as a normal directory name.

#### [`File::expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path)

> Converts a pathname to an absolute pathname. Relative paths are
>   referenced from the current working directory of the process unless
>   dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting
>   point. The given pathname may start with a “~”, which expands to the
>   process owner’s home directory (the environment variable HOME must be
>   set correctly). “~user” expands to the named user’s home directory.